# Get child of unique parent

Tags: arrays, actionscript, parent, hittest

I'm currently working on some code for a project. The question is about targeting child with a unique parent. For example. Let's say I have a box people can move called `box_mc` and 3 platforms it can jump on called:

- Platform_1
- Platform_2
- Platform_3

All of these platforms have a child element called hit.

- Platform_1

  - Hit
- Platform_2

  - Hit
- Platform_3

  - Hit

I use an array and a `for each` statement to detect if `box_mc` hits one of the platforms childs.

```
var obj_arr:Array = [Platform_1, Platform_2, Platform_3];
for each(obj in obj_arr){
   if(box_mc.hitTestObject(obj.hit)){
      trace(obj + " " + obj.hit);
      box_mc.y = obj.hit.y - box_mc.height;
   }
}
```

obj seems to output the unique parent it is hitting but obj.hit ouputs hit so my theory in this is that it is applying the change of y to all the childs called hit in the stage. WOuld it be possible to only detect the child of that specific parent?

Thanks in advance again guys!

Comment: What's the problem? In the code you've posted you're not altering the y property of the hit element.

Comment: Plus, the instance name inside all of your parent MC's is actually hit, so of course it will trace that?